# Can a FlowLayoutPanel auto-fit to a resizable panel?

Tags: .net, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to create a form that I can most easily describe as being like an Explorer view, with two panels side-by-side (a list of folders on the left, files within the selected folder shown on the right).

The left-hand panel is fixed-width, and docked to the left of the form. It works fine, and isn't relevant here.

The right-hand panel is positioned to the right of the left-hand panel, filling the remainder of the form, and anchored top, left, bottom & right so that, as the form resizes, it continues to occupy the whole of the form except that part occupied by the left-hand panel. It also has `AutoScroll` set to `True` so that whenever the content is too big to fit, it automatically displays scrollbars. That part works fine too.

Because I want to show different things in the right-hand panel at different times, I've created an ordinary `Panel` as a container, and am using child panels for each of the different types of content. Only one of these child panels will be visible at any one time.

One of the things I (sometimes) want to display in the right-hand panel is a very much like the "icon" view in Explorer - i.e. a bunch of file icons, and for this a `FlowLayoutPanel` sounds perfect, since I do want them to be arranged left-to-right but then wrapping onto a new row as required.

I would have thought this was exactly what a `FlowLayoutPanel` was designed for, but I can't get it to work! [I set the `Dock` property of the `FlowLayoutPanel` to `Fill` so that it uses all the space available in the parent `Panel`.] What actually happens is that it just displays all the icons in a single row, and never wraps them. I end up with a horizontal scrollbar on the parent `Panel` because the `FlowLayoutPanel` does not fit.

I think this might be because the parent `Panel` that contains the `FlowLayoutPanel` does not have a fixed size (since it will grow and shrink with the form), and so I guess when the `FlowLayoutPanel` decides how wide it can afford to be, it decides that it can be as wide as it likes. However, that's not very helpful.

Is there any way I can persuade the `FlowLayoutPanel` that it should only be as wide as its parent `Panel`?

Comment: Note: I've found a hack that seems to work - I override the MaximumSize property of the FlowLayoutPanel and return the current Width of the parent Panel (plus unbounded height). This seems to do the trick, though I have to then pull an additional stunt to get the scrollbars working correctly on the parent Panel - I need to reset the AutoScrollMinimumSize every time the parent Panel is resized (as a result of resizing the form), since a change in the size of the Form/Parent means that dimensions of the inner FlowLayoutPanel may change greatly due to re-flow.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you have the FLP's `WrapContents` option enabled.

If you've already done that, my guess is that having the FLP's parent Panel `AutoScroll` option enabled is the cause. This is incompatible with the desired wrapping behavior of the FLP. The FLP won't wrap unless it can't fit everything on one line. By allowing its parent Panel to scroll, the FLP will always be able to fit everything on one line. Turn the parent Panel's `AutoScroll` off and it should work.

Comment: WrapContents is enabled. And I need the AutoScroll on, because I need to be able to scroll if the *height* gets too big.

Comment: Also, the user may re-size the form down such that even one column of icons no longer fits. So I need horizontal scrolling too.